# Trying to understand jquery serialization

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm working with PHP making a form and using regular PHP it works just fine but using jquery it doesn't work anymore. I checked if it was utf-8 but the problem occurs in this method that worked in the normal submit:

```
public function save_to_DAO()
    {
        if ($this->questions)
        {
            try 
            {
                $data = json_encode($this->questions);
                $prev = $this->get_from_DAO();
                $form = $this->questions;
                if(isset($prev)){
                    $arr = array_merge( $prev, $form );
                    $data = json_encode($arr);
                }
                $w = file_put_contents('questions.json', $data);
                if($w && $w > 0) {
                    return true;
                }

            }
            catch (exception $e) 
            {
                 die ('ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage() . $this->questions);    
                 return false;

            }

        }
    }
```

This is the request:

```
function postQuestion(){

    $('.js-submit').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.post("create_quiz_op.php", $('#qform').serialize(), getQuestions(displayQuestions));
    });

}
```

This is the PHP handler:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') 
{
    $questions = [];
    $cq = new CreateQuizController();

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {

            $question = new Question();
            $question->set_id($_POST['id']);
            $question->set_question($_POST['question']);

            for ($j = 0; $j < count($_POST['answers']); $j++)
            {
                $question->set_answer($_POST['answers'][$j]);
            }

            $question->set_right_answer($_POST['right_answer']);

            $questions[] = $question;   

    }


    $cq->set_questions($questions);

    if($cq->save_to_DAO())
    {
        print_r(json_encode($cq->get_from_DAO()));
        print_r("\n");


    } 
    else {
        echo "Problema";
    }

}

?>
```

The call reports on the browser developer tools show that it's not successful. The call reaches PHP but it is not processed successfully.

Comment: maybe you have wrong content type defined in ajax. Try this multipart/form-data. Or check which data are posted in request.

Comment: sometimes form.serialize not send key = val but crap.

Comment: This is what it is sending: id=0&question=Whats+1+plus+1%3F&answers%5B%5D=1&answers%5B%5D=2&answers%5B%5D=3&answers%5B%5D=4&right_answer=2

Comment: the values should be readable in the post\get array as 'normal' in the php

Comment: $_POST['submit'] .. how you can catch submit on ajax request if value submit not exist in your data?

Comment: When I change .click for .submit it doesn't change and the button does have an input button with value 'submit'.

Comment: How do I add 'submit' to that string anyway?     This is the button:    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary js-submit" value="submit" />

Comment: so your php cant handle request because POST value SUBMIT not exist. Add hidden field with value SUBMIT and should work.

Comment: serialize doesn't do anything with submit buttons. Would need to set a hidden input or ignore it in php

Comment: Thanks, that's the issue! I had to remove the isset($_POST['submit']) as the value doesn't exist.